# Closed-form of an two-dimensional integral

Tags: definite-integrals, closed-form

I want to ask a quick question, i.e., how to calculate the below integral
\begin{align*}
I=\int_{0}^{\pi}dx\int_{0}^{\pi}dy \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4\cos^2x+4\cos x\cos y}}
\end{align*}
I mean what's the closed-form of it.

I don't know if the substitution $u=\cos(x), v=\cos(y)$ is a good starting point. Thanks.

Here below is the code in ${\textit{Mathematica}}$

X = Integrate[(1/Sqrt[1 + 4*Cos[x]*Cos[x] + 4*Cos[x]*Cos[y]])  Boole[
    0 <= y < Pi && 0 <= x < Pi], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}]; N[X, 5]

and the result is 8.8475.

Comment: The `Boole` factor seems redundant.